# How to add Line Numbers through menuitem using swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to display line numbers through JMenuItem.  But, it was display line numbers separate frame not currently opened frame and the create menuitem is also not working after click on viewLineNumbers.

Here is my code:

```
public class LineNumbers extends javax.swing.JFrame {
int i=0;
JTextArea tx,lines;
public LineNumbers() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    file = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    create = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    viewLineNumbers = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    scrollPane.setViewportView(tabbedPane);

    file.setText("File");

    create.setText("Create");
    create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            createActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    file.add(create);

    viewLineNumbers.setSelected(true);
    viewLineNumbers.setText("ViewLineNumbers");
    viewLineNumbers.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            viewLineNumbersActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    file.add(viewLineNumbers);

    menuBar.add(file);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 403, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 354, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
    i++;
    internalFrame.setName("Document"+i);
    internalFrame.setClosable(true);
    tx = new JTextArea();
    internalFrame.add(tx, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    tabbedPane.add(internalFrame);
    internalFrame.pack();
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);
}                                      

private void viewLineNumbersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
            lines = new JTextArea("");
    lines.setEditable(false);
            lines.setSize(10,10);
    tx.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
        public String getText(){
            int caretPosition = tx.getDocument().getLength();
            Element root = tx.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
            String text = "1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                            int c=root.getElementIndex( caretPosition );
            for(int i = 2; i < c + 2; i++){
                text += i + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            }
            return text;
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            lines.setText(getText());
        }
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            lines.setText(getText());
        }
                    @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            lines.setText(getText());
        }
    });
            scrollPane.getViewport().add(tx);
            scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(lines);
}                                               
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LineNumbers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LineNumbers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LineNumbers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LineNumbers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new LineNumbers().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem create;
private javax.swing.JMenu file;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem viewLineNumbers;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Start accepting answers. You got the idea to add the component to the row header of the scroll pane from your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859721/jtextarea-line-numbers-of-menu-item).

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add the text area to a scroll pane and then add the scroll pane to the internal frame.
2. Then you update the row header of the above scroll pane (that contains the text area), NOT the scroll pane that contains the tabbed pane.